# How is a Postgres "RAISE EXCEPTION" converted into a PDOException?

Tags: php, postgresql, exception

I am trying to figure out which "parts" of "RAISE EXCEPTION" statement gets mapped into which "parts" of PDOException.  Can some one explain "who" and "how" perform this conversion (or better yet, point to document which describes this or source code which performs this)?

More specifically, I would like to know if there is a way to affect SQLSTATUS value (in my tests its always 'P0001') and/or 'ERROR:' value (which is part of the message and is always empty)

Best I could manage is:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION USING message = '<a message>', ERRCODE = 'UE001'
```

which on PHP side gives me message like:

```
ERROR:  NUM:UE001, DETAILS:<a message>
```

But I am not very happy with this. It would be great to be able to "put" 'UE001' into one of PDOException fields (so I do not have to parse it out of message string).

You comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please *always* show your code and PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `code` property of `PDOException` to get the `SQLSTATE`. See [the documentation for `PDOException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php#pdoexception.props.code)

To control the `SQLSTATE` generated by a PL/PgSQL function raising an error, you use [`RAISE ... SQLSTATE` as per the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).

Of course, for this to work the database driver must correctly report `SQLSTATE`. I have verified that PDO does this at least in PHP 5.4.11 with PostgreSQL 9.2, per the following standalone example code that can be executed with the `php` command-line executable:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('pgsql:');

$sql = <<<EOD
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exceptiondemo() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE SQLSTATE 'UE001' USING MESSAGE = 'error message';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
EOD;

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if (!$sth->execute()) {
        die("Failed to create test function\n");
}

$sql = "SELECT exceptiondemo();";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if (!$sth->execute()) {
        $ei = $sth->errorInfo();
        die("Function call failed with SQLSTATE " . $ei[0] . ", message " . $ei[2] . "\n");

        // Shortcut way:
        // die("Function call failed with SQLSTATE " . $sth->errorCode());
}
?>
```

Output is:

```
Function call failed with SQLSTATE UE001, message ERROR:  error message
```

Replace the code block from the second `$sth->execute()` to the end of the code with this to demonstrate that the exception handling mode works fine too:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
        $sth->execute();
} catch (PDOException $err) {
        $ei = $err->errorInfo;
        die("Function call failed with SQLSTATE " . $ei[0] . ", message " . $ei[2] . "\n");

        // Alternate version to just get code:
        //die("Function call failed with SQLSTATE " . $err->getCode() . "\n");
}
```

Comment: @AndreiTchijov Answer amended.

Comment: @AndreiTchijov Is it possible you're on an old PostgreSQL version that doesn't support user-defined SQLSTATE on RAISE? What's your PostgreSQL version? (You should really always mention this in questions).

Comment: @AndreiTchijov Otherwise, please show a fully self-contained code example demonstrating the problem, because it works fine for me as shown above in edited answer. Specify the PHP version, Pg version, and the platform you're on.

Comment: Ok, mystery has been resolved (and I am an idiot).  There is 'EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'NUM:%, DETAILS:%', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM
  ;' further in the SPROC which was throwing exception I was having issues with.  The only excuse I have - this is bloody big SPROC.

Comment: just for self education, do you know where '7' from errorInfo[1] coming from?

Comment: @AndreiTchijov `7`? I don't know what you mean. Context? I don't see what you mean in my answer or your question.

Comment: errorInfo array contains 3 elements: first one is SQLSTATE, last one is actual message, the middle one (errorInfo[1]) is number 7.

Comment: @AndreiTchijov Did you look at the documentation for `PDOException`? It links to `PDOStatement::errorInfo` which explains the values.

Comment: @AndreiTchijov As you can see it's a driver-specific error value. Unless you have a reason to care, ignore it.