# insert into postgres db with for php statement

Tags: php, postgresql, for-loop

I'm writing a code with this function:

```
function foo() {

    $input = array('bar');

    for ($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {

        $db=connection_pgsql() or die('Connessione al DBMS non riuscita');

            pg_prepare( "run","INSERT INTO tab1(name) VALUES  ($1)");
            pg_execute("run",$input);

            pg_prepare( "run","INSERT INTO tab2(name) VALUES  ($1)");
            pg_execute("run",$input);

            pg_prepare( "run","INSERT INTO tab3(name) VALUES  ($1)");
            pg_execute("run",$input);

        pg_close($db);


    }
}
```

After the execution of this function there are only

**20** rows in tab1, **20** rows in tab2 and **20** rows in tab3

and not

**1000** rows in tab1, **1000** rows in tab2 and **1000** rows in tab3.

Is it a problem of php or postgresql configuration?

Comment: I don't know php but you need to inspect the results of those inserts. Could be failing a constraint or something

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking for errors.

Check the return value of functions and use the error info functions provided by PHP.

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-last-error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php

You can also check the PostgreSQL error logs.

It's much clearer if you use PDO; see e.g. [How is a Postgres "RAISE EXCEPTION" converted into a PDOException?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15421981/398670) .

Also, don't open and close connections each loop iteration like this, the performance will be *awful*. Preferably do all the work in a single transaction on a single connection.

Comment: I printed for each row last error, result error and affecter rows. Last error and result error are nulls, affected rows is 1. I try with only 1 table insert in a for of 1000 statements. Only 130 are execute...

Comment: please update your question then (preferably with smaller iteration number - eg loops over 20 times, inserts only 19 rows) and result error is null or so.

Comment: Don't print the results, check for errors exit the loop. You can easily miss something when you're reading 1000 lines of output.

Comment: there aren't error in loop. It only stops after n rows.

Answer (score 0):

check the resource returned or at least if it is not `false`. Look at [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php) example, you should not just `pg_execute("run",$input);`, but

```
$result = pg_execute("run",$input);
```

so you can run

```
var_dump($result);
```

This way you will see full dump of value returned on your html page.

Comment: var_dump($result) returns: resource(number of $i) of type (pgsql result)